# Need to filter data based on multiple classes data

Tags: c#

I have 3 classes like below,

```
public class Main
{
    public string MainName { get; set; }
    public List<SubClass1> SubClass1S { get; set; }

    public List<SubClass2> SubClass2S { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass1
{
    public string SubClass1Name { get; set; }
}

public class SubClass2
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Config { get; set; }
}
```

and below are my sample data,

```
var lsMains = new List<Main>();

        var main1 = new Main
        {
            MainName = "main1",
            SubClass1S = new List<SubClass1> { new SubClass1 { SubClass1Name = "sub1" }, new SubClass1 { SubClass1Name = "sub2" } },
            SubClass2S = new List<SubClass2> { new SubClass2 { Name = "N1", Config = "C1" } }
        };

        lsMains.Add(main1);

        var main2 = new Main
        {
            MainName = "main2",
            SubClass1S = new List<SubClass1> { new SubClass1 { SubClass1Name = "sub1" } },
            SubClass2S = new List<SubClass2> { new SubClass2 { Name = "N1", Config = "C1" }, new SubClass2 { Name = "N2", Config = "C2" } }
        };

        lsMains.Add(main2);

        var main3 = new Main
        {
            MainName = "main3",
            SubClass1S = new List<SubClass1> { new SubClass1 { SubClass1Name = "sub3" } },
            SubClass2S = new List<SubClass2> { new SubClass2 { Name = "N1", Config = "C1" }, new SubClass2 { Name = "N2", Config = "C2" } }
        };

        lsMains.Add(main2);
```

Now, I need to filter data,

1. where `SubClass1Name = "sub1"` and count of list of `SubClass1` = 1
2. where `SubClass2` config is "C1", `Config = "C1"`

The result class should be like this,

```
var result = new Result
        {
            MainName = "main2",
            SubClass2Config = "C1",
            SubClass2Name = "N1"
        };
```

I tried this, how to filter on 2nd class `SubClass2`? Thanks!

```
var X1 = lsMains.Where(x => x.SubClass1S.Count == 1).ToList();
        foreach (var x in X1)
        {
            if (x.SubClass1S.Where(y => y.SubClass1Name == "sub1"))
            {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var parentFilteredList = lsMains
            .Where(c => c.SubClass1S.Any(d => d.SubClass1Name == "sub1") 
                        &&  c.SubClass2S.Any(d => d.Config == "C1") 
                        &&  c.SubClass1S.Count == 1)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks... How to add filter  for subclass2

Comment: filter is here: &&  c.SubClass2S.Any(d => d.Config == "C1")